# Getting touch event in any view (Android)

Tags: android, events, touch

I need to make a service that capture all touch events, not in a specific view or when an specific activity is open. This service is started when the boot is completed (and I have an app to stop/play this service when I want it). So it write something (in a Toast) when the user touch any place in the screen.

Can I do this? Or only in specifics things (with OnTouchListener and adding specifics views, for example)?

Sorry for my bad english.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you override the View itself and build your own ROM, you will be able to have these kind of things. So, straight answer will be just no. Sorry.